# Change the Font size through Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are fetching Text from JSON & display in page....

[image]

Once user click on Text, we are displaying pop up box....

[image]

In Pop up box , We are displaying **Slider** to **change** the **Font-size** of **text** as [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/te26zsn7/)....

**Issue** :

But in Below Code snippet, Font-size is not changing....

Here is Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/vMpBrd

```js
// Display pop up next to text
function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    ///console.log(" open is called ",id)
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }
    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}


let openID = null;


var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
   "layers":[  
      {  
         "x":0,
         "height":612,
         "layers":[  
            {  
               "x":160,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":66,
                     "y":93,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
                     "type":"text",
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"MAYER'S ANNUAL",
                     "name":"edit_mayer"
                  }
               ],
               "y":291,
               "name":"user_image_1"
            },
            {  
               "x":25,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":166,
                     "y":193,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "type":"text",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"SALE",
                     "name":"edit_sale"
                  }
               ],
               "y":22,
               "name":"L2"
            }
         ],
         "y":0,
         "width":612,
         "name":"L1"
      }
   ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   
    // Below code will fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                    
            };
            counter++;
        }
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

// Text code

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +
   $('#template2').html() + 
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
        // Above is POP UP Code
    }

}
// extempl code end 

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
      

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };       
     };
}(jQuery));

// slider text

$('input').on('input', function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(text).css('font-size', v + 'px')
});
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container"></div>

<template id='template2'>
  <input type="range" min="10" max="40">
</template>
```

Comment: In trying to debug the code, I seemed to have noticed that there is bad HTML format. it seems to generate code like this: 
    `<a id="edit_mayer" onclick="openPopUp(lightedit_mayer)" <div="" class="txtContainer" contenteditable="true" style="left: 66px; top: 93px; font-size: 60px; ">MAYER'S ANNUAL</a>` notice that the div tag starts before the closing of the beginning of the `<a>` tag (I.E. no `>`)

Comment: @Chucky Thanks for the hint, but why `id = "text"` is not displaying in inspect element ? is that is the reason as id `text` is not loading?

Comment: @Chucky yes, i wanted to display like this : `<a><div>content</div></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just update your script with few fixes, but you also have to update your code structure. Right now your code is a bit complex and confusing. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
// Display pop up next to text
function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    ///console.log(" open is called ",id)
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }
    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}

function fontRange(e) {
  var element = e.parentElement.id;
  element = "#edit_" + element.split("_")[1];
  $(element).css('font-size', e.value + 'px');
}

let openID = null;


var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
   "layers":[  
      {  
         "x":0,
         "height":612,
         "layers":[  
            {  
               "x":160,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":66,
                     "y":93,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
                     "type":"text",
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"MAYER'S ANNUAL",
                     "name":"edit_mayer"
                  }
               ],
               "y":291,
               "name":"user_image_1"
            },
            {  
               "x":25,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":166,
                     "y":193,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "type":"text",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"SALE",
                     "name":"edit_sale"
                  }
               ],
               "y":22,
               "name":"L2"
            }
         ],
         "y":0,
         "width":612,
         "name":"L1"
      }
   ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   
    // Below code will fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                    
            };
            counter++;
        }
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

// Text code

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +
   $('#template2').html() + 
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
        // Above is POP UP Code
    }

}
// extempl code end 

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
      

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };       
     };
}(jQuery));

// slider text

$('input').on('input', function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    $(text).css('font-size', v + 'px')
});
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container"></div>

<template id='template2'>
  <input type="range" min="10" max="40" oninput="fontRange(this)" onchange="fontRange(this)">
</template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked fine.... once the size of text decreased, text moving left side.... but it should be in same place as [link](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150) , please help me for that.....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$(input).on('input', function () {
  ...
});
```

Use

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks,  i updated your code, but no luck : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/KYZKRN , i got ` Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined`

Comment: why id = "text" is not displaying in inspect element ? is that is the reason for issue?

Comment: Instead of $(text), you need to use the valid identifier for you text container. text is nowhere defined in the code. May be in openPopUp, save the reference of clicked element and use the same to increase font.

Comment: in div i used this code : `<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true"` , so i thought `$(text)` will work.... if possible please help me with updated code.....

Comment: try this $('#' + openID.id.replace('light', '')).css('font-size', v + 'px')
});

Comment: also before we leave the mouse, font-size should increase as here : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/te26zsn7/ , but now after we leave mouse, then only its reflecting font-size, please help me for that https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/KYZKRN.....

Comment: thats okay, with help of other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705799/change-the-font-size-through-slider/55708289#55708289) , now font-size varying before i leave the mouse...... Thanks for your valuable time....

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why you just don't modify the DIV style property... something like this (not tested):

```
$('.container').style.fontSize = value
```

See if that'll work

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input").change(function(){
  var size= $(this).val();
  
  $("p").css("font-size", size +"px");
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="20" max="90">

<p>Hello</p>
```

1. Set the minimum and maximum value in the range slider.
2. Then using the event onchange in the input get the value of range slider.
3. Save that value in a variable.
4. Then use that variable wherever needed.

Let me know if this is fine as reference.

Comment: thanks for codepen, but i already have solution for simple text : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/te26zsn7/ but when i integrate code in my project, it gave errors as i mentioned in question.....

Comment: yes, requirement is like that only : `<a><div>content</div></a>` i also dont have any idea why id="text" is not loading in inspect element.... can you please check once....

Comment: Please check that you have ID in two Places in the DOM. Remember that ID is always unique.

Comment: Please tell where you see `id` in 2 places ? can you tell me the lines ?

Answer (score 0):

I little changed your range function below.

```js
// Display pop up next to text
function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    ///console.log(" open is called ",id)
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }
    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}


let openID = null;


var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
   "layers":[  
      {  
         "x":0,
         "height":612,
         "layers":[  
            {  
               "x":160,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":66,
                     "y":93,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
                     "type":"text",
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"MAYER'S ANNUAL",
                     "name":"edit_mayer"
                  }
               ],
               "y":291,
               "name":"user_image_1"
            },
            {  
               "x":25,
               "layers":[  
                  {  
                     "font":"Montserrat-Bold",
                     "x":166,
                     "y":193,
      "width" : 801,
      "height" : 371,
      "src" : "a7bde03063d9fc0ef14eecd18f7eba31_Font522.otf",
                     "type":"text",
                     "size":60,
                     "text":"SALE",
                     "name":"edit_sale"
                  }
               ],
               "y":22,
               "name":"L2"
            }
         ],
         "y":0,
         "width":612,
         "name":"L1"
      }
   ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
   
    // Below code will fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
            
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                    
            };
            counter++;
        }
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

// Text code

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +
   $('#template2').html() + 
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close</a></div> <div>'
        );
        document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px'
        // Above is POP UP Code
    }

}
// extempl code end 

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
      

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            //if (img)
            // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
            // sirpepole  Add this
            return settings.id;
        };       
     };
}(jQuery));

// slider text

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[type=range]").change(function(){
    var v =$(this).val();
    $(".txtContainer").css('font-size', v+ 'px');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
 background: gold;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFF
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 background: red;
 padding: 1px;
 border-style: dotted;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container"></div>

<template id='template2'>
  <input id="rangeInput" type="range" min="10" max="40">
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please try to increase font-size of `SALE` also ?

Comment: I changed little bit to is this OK?

Comment: no, not like that, when we try for `Mayers annual` , it should change the font only for `mayers annual` , when we try for `sale` , it should change the font only for `sale`

Comment: you should manage this code like that i answer it how to do ?

Comment: both have different ids : `edit_mayer & edit_sale` , please check inspect element..

Comment: the issue is =  But in Below Code snippet, Font-size is not changing...
now font-size is changing. u asked is a diffirent question. Here is not " this ist what i want can you make it " here is i did something but it not works, so i solved the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191912/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-bmerer).